# How does JDBC/Postgres compare a timezone-less java.util.Date with a Timestamp?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, time

We have a [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) table that has two [`TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) columns, prc_sta_dt and prc_end_dt. We check to see whether a `java.util.Date` falls in between the start and end dates.

Here is some of the Java code, which is simplified but gets the point across.

```
// This format expects a String such as 2018-12-03T10:00:00
// With a date and a time, but no time zone

String timestamp = "2018-12-03T10:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date searchDate = formatter.parse(timestamp);

// Here's the Postgres query

String query = "select promotion_cd from promotions " + 
               "where prc_sta_dt <= :srch_dt and prc_end_dt >= :srch_dt";

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("srch_dt", searchDate);

List<Promotion> promotions = jdbcTemplate.query(query, map, promotionMapper);
```

In our Postgres table, we have promotions that start at 9am on 12/3/2018 and end at 3pm on the same day. The prc_sta_dt and prc_end_dt colums in our database for these rows are `2018-12-03 09:00:00.0` and `2018-12-03 15:00:00.0`

**Question:** When [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)/Postgres accepts our `searchDate` and compares it to these timestamps, will it accept the given search date of 10am (2018-12-03T10:00:00) or will it treat this time as being under the time zone that the server is running on, and then convert that to UTC?

For example, if the server is running in Chicago, then will it interpret 10 am as 10am CST and then convert that to 4pm UTC before doing the comparison in the database? If so then we're out of luck!

I doubt this would happen, but I just want to make sure so there are no surprises.

Comment: All it can do with the timezone-less timestamp is assume that it's GMT or the client timezone.

Comment: @duffymo But there's a big difference between those two assumptions. If the client timezone is CST, then will it convert 10am CST to 4pm GMT before comparing with the timestamps in the database?

Comment: Sure.  Big difference.  Best approach is to not guess and not depend on defaults.

Comment: You should be passing instances of `java.sql.Timestamp` **not** `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 5):

## Wrong data type, `Date` is not a date

A `java.util.Date` object represents a **moment** in UTC, a specific point on the timeline. So it represents the combination of a date, a time-of-day, and an offset-from-UTC of zero (for UTC itself). Among the many poor design choices in this terrible class is its misleading name that has confused countless Java programmers.

### `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

If you care about moments, then your database column should *not* be of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. That data type represents a date and a time-of-day without any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, by definition, that type cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. This type should only be used when you mean a date-with-time *anywhere* or *everywhere*.

Examples:

- “Christmas starts after stroke of midnight at beginning of December 25, 2018” where Christmas in [Kiribati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiribati) comes first, India later, and Africa even later.
- “Company-wide memo: Each of our factories in Delhi, Düsseldorf, and Detroit will close one hour early at 16:00 on January 21st” where 4 PM at each factory is three different moments, each several hours apart.

### `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

When tracking specific a specific moment, a single point on the timeline, use a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In Postgres, such values are stored in UTC. Any time zone or offset info submitted with an input is used to adjust into UTC, then the zone/offset info is discarded.

**BEWARE:** Some tools may have the well-intentioned but unfortunate anti-feature of injecting a time zone after retrieving the value in UTC, thereby misrepresenting what was actually stored.

## Comparing a moment to values of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

As for comparing a moment to values in your column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, doing so would **generally not make sense**.

But if you are clear-headed and educated about date-time handling, and making this comparison is sensible in your business logic, let's forge on.

## Wrong classes

You are using lousy, terrible, awful date-time classes (`Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.) that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Do yourself a favor: Stop using the legacy date-time classes. Use only *java.time*.

If given a moment as a `java.util.Date`, use the new methods added to the old classes to convert. In particular, `java.util.Date` is replaced by `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
```

Specify the time zone in which you want to adjust your `Instant` moment in UTC for comparison. For example, if your database was built by someone who did not understand proper date-time handling, and has been using the `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column to store date-with-time values that were taken from the wall-clock time of Québec, then use the time zone `America/Montreal`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Apply that zone to our `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Our resulting `ZonedDateTime` object represents the same moment as the `Instant` object, same point on the timeline, but viewed with a different wall-clock time.

To hammer a [square-peg into a round-hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole), let's convert that `ZonedDateTime` object to a `LocalDateTime` object, thereby stripping away the time zone information and leaving only a date-with-time-of-day value.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime() ;
```

## Half-Open

```sql
where prc_sta_dt <= :srch_dt and prc_end_dt >= :srch_dt
```

That logic is prone to failure. Generally, the best practice in date-time handling when defining a span-of-time to use Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So use this:

```sql
WHERE instant >= start_col AND instant < stop_col ;
```

For a `PreparedStatement`, we would have placeholders.

```sql
WHERE ? >= start_col AND ? < stop_col ;
```

On the Java side, as of JDBC 4.2 we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database via `getObject` and `setObject` methods.

You *might* be able to pass an `Instant` depending on your JDBC driver. Support for `Instant` is not required by the JDBC spec. So try it, or read the doc for your driver.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , instant ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , instant ) ;
```

If `Instant` is not supported, convert from `Instant` to an `OffsetDateTime` set to UTC. Support for `OffsetDateTime` *is* required by the spec.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Always specify time zone

> For example, if the server is running in Chicago, then will it interpret 10 am as 10am CST and then convert that to 4pm UTC before doing the comparison in the database?

A programmer should *never* depend on the time zone (or locale, by the way) currently set as the default on the host OS or JVM. Both are out of your control. And both can change *at any moment* during runtime!

Always specify the time zone by passing the optional argument to various date-time methods. Making those optional was a design flaw in *java.time* in my opinion, as programmers all too often ignore the issue of time zone, at their own peril. But that is one of very few design flaws in an amazingly useful and elegant framework.

Notice in our code above we specified the desired/expected time zone. The current default time zone of our host OS, our Postgres database connection, and our JVM will not alter the behavior of our code.

## Current moment

If you want the current moment use any of these:

- `Instant.now()`
  Always in UTC, by definition.
- `OffsetDateTime.now( someZoneOffset )`
  Current moment as seen in the wall-clock time of a particular offset-from-UTC.
- `ZonedDateTime.now( someZoneId )`
  Current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people living in a particular region.

## Java 7 and *ThreeTen-Backport*

If you are using Java 7, then you have no *java.time* classes built-in. Fortunately, the inventor of [JSR 310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) and *java.time*, Stephen Colebourne, also led the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project to produce a library providing most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.

Here is a complete example app in a single .java file showing the use of back-port in Java 7 with the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)).

In [Java 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7), [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) is not available, so we cannot directly use the modern classes. We fall back to using [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) which actually represents a moment in UTC, but which H2 stores into a column of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` taking the date and the time-of-day as-is (using the wall-clock time of UTC) while ignoring the UTC aspect. I have not tried this in Postgres, but I expect you will see the same behavior.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;

import org.threeten.bp.*;

public class App {
    static final public String databaseConnectionString = "jdbc:h2:mem:localdatetime_example;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";  // The `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` keeps the in-memory database around for multiple connections.

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt () {
        System.out.println( "Bonjour tout le monde!" );

//        java.sql.Timestamp ts = DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() );
//        System.out.println( ts );

        this.makeDatabase();

        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(); // Capture the current moment using terrible old date-time class that is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the class `java.time.Instant`.
        this.fetchRowsContainingMoment( d );
    }

    private void makeDatabase () {
        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( databaseConnectionString ) ;  // The `mem` means “In-Memory”, as in “Not persisted to disk”, good for a demo.
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE event_ ( \n" +
                             "  pkey_ IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
                             "  name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL , \n" +
                             "  start_ TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL , \n" +
                             "  stop_ TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL \n" +
                             ");";
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( name_ , start_ , stop_ ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? ) ;";
            try (
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
            ) {
                preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , "Alpha" );
                // We have to “fake it until we make it”, using a `java.sql.Timestamp` with its value in UTC while pretending it is not in a zone or offset.
                // The legacy date-time classes lack a way to represent a date with time-of-day without any time zone or offset-from-UTC.
                // The legacy classes have no counterpart to `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in SQL, and have no counterpart to `java.time.LocalDateTime` in Java.
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() ) );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 3 , DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 2 , 23 , 12 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() ) );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , "Beta" );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 4 , 23 , 14 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() ) );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 3 , DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 5 , 23 , 14 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() ) );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , "Gamma" );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 11 , 23 , 16 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() ) );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 3 , DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 12 , 23 , 16 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() ) );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void fetchRowsContainingMoment ( java.util.Date moment ) {
        // Immediately convert the legacy class `java.util.Date` to a modern `java.time.Instant`.
        Instant instant = DateTimeUtils.toInstant( moment );
        System.out.println( "instant.toString(): " + instant );
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ WHERE ? >= start_ AND ? < stop_ ORDER BY start_ ;";

        try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( databaseConnectionString ) ;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        ) {
            java.sql.Timestamp ts = DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( instant );
            pstmt.setTimestamp( 1 , ts );
            pstmt.setTimestamp( 2 , ts );

            try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery() ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    Integer pkey = rs.getInt( "pkey_" );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    java.sql.Timestamp start = rs.getTimestamp( "start_" );
                    java.sql.Timestamp stop = rs.getTimestamp( "stop_" );

                    // Instantiate a `Course` object for this data.
                    System.out.println( "Event pkey: " + pkey + " | name: " + name + " | start: " + start + " | stop: " + stop );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

> instant.toString(): 2018-12-04T05:06:02.573Z
>
> Event pkey: 3 | name: Gamma | start: 2018-11-23 16:30:00.0 | stop: 2018-12-23 16:30:00.0

## Java 8 without *ThreeTen-Backport*

And here is that same example, conceptually, but in Java 8 or later where we can use the *java.time* classes built-in without the *ThreeTen-Backport* library.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;

import java.time.*;

public class App {
    static final public String databaseConnectionString = "jdbc:h2:mem:localdatetime_example;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";  // The `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` keeps the in-memory database around for multiple connections.

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        System.out.println( "Bonjour tout le monde!" );

        this.makeDatabase();

        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(); // Capture the current moment using terrible old date-time class that is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the class `java.time.Instant`.
        this.fetchRowsContainingMoment( d );
    }

    private void makeDatabase ( ) {
        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( databaseConnectionString ) ;  // The `mem` means “In-Memory”, as in “Not persisted to disk”, good for a demo.
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE event_ ( \n" +
                    "  pkey_ IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
                    "  name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL , \n" +
                    "  start_ TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL , \n" +
                    "  stop_ TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL \n" +
                    ");";
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( name_ , start_ , stop_ ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? ) ;";
            try (
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
            ) {
                preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , "Alpha" );
                // We have to “fake it until we make it”, using a `java.sql.Timestamp` with its value in UTC while pretending it is not in a zone or offset.
                // The legacy date-time classes lack a way to represent a date with time-of-day without any time zone or offset-from-UTC.
                // The legacy classes have no counterpart to `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in SQL, and have no counterpart to `java.time.LocalDateTime` in Java.
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() );
                ;
                preparedStatement.setObject( 3 , ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 2 , 23 , 12 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , "Beta" );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 4 , 23 , 14 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 3 , ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 5 , 23 , 14 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , "Gamma" );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 11 , 23 , 16 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 3 , ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 12 , 23 , 16 , 30 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDateTime() );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void fetchRowsContainingMoment ( java.util.Date moment ) {
        // Immediately convert the legacy class `java.util.Date` to a modern `java.time.Instant`.
        Instant instant = moment.toInstant();
        System.out.println( "instant.toString(): " + instant );
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ WHERE ? >= start_ AND ? < stop_ ORDER BY start_ ;";

        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( databaseConnectionString ) ;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        ) {
            pstmt.setObject( 1 , instant );
            pstmt.setObject( 2 , instant );

            try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery() ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    Integer pkey = rs.getInt( "pkey_" );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    Instant start = rs.getObject( "start_" , OffsetDateTime.class ).toInstant();
                    Instant stop = rs.getObject( "stop_" , OffsetDateTime.class ).toInstant();

                    // Instantiate a `Course` object for this data.
                    System.out.println( "Event pkey: " + pkey + " | name: " + name + " | start: " + start + " | stop: " + stop );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

> instant.toString(): 2018-12-04T05:10:54.635Z
>
> Event pkey: 3 | name: Gamma | start: 2018-11-24T00:30:00Z | stop: 2018-12-24T00:30:00Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Two things. First, in my SQuirreL SQL client, it describes the column as a "timestamp" without indicating whether there's a time zone or not. But I assume there's no time zone since all the timestamps in this table are lacking time zones. Second, I'm stuck with using `java.util.Date` -- there's no way around it -- since all our infrastructure uses this class. Given the two points above, what will happen if we compare a `java.util.Date` that was initialized as shown above to the timestamps in our table?

Comment: @ktm5124 [As documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), `TIMESTAMP` is an abbreviation of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in Postgres.

Comment: @ktm5124 As for `java.util.Date`, you should *definitely* be using only *java.time* in all your new code or rewritten code, without a doubt. To interoperate with the old code, convert back-and-forth between legacy classes and modern classes using the new conversion methods added to the old classes. The conversion methods are on the old classes so that someday in the far future the legacy classes can be removed from Java, and not pollute the modern classes. Look for `to…` and `from…` method names on the old classes.

Comment: I see. But I **absolutely** have to use `java.util.Date`. There's simply no way around it. All our infrastructure uses it. I would have to rewrite the entire infrastructure. Considering this, what will happen if we go ahead and compare a `java.util.Date` with a Postgres Timestamp?? I understand it's not the best way to do things, but the question is, what will the behavior be? We initialize our Date as shown in my question above, parsing a timezone-less ISO-8601 string.

Comment: Also... we're stuck with running Java 7 since one of our customers runs Java 7. So the new conversion methods added in Java 8 are no solution.

Comment: Reread my comments and Answer. I never said rewrite your entire infrastructure. Converting back and forth between legacy and modern is easy-peasy. `Instant`↔`java.util.Date`. `ZonedDateTime`↔`GregorianCalendar` (usually the concrete class behind `Calendar`). `LocalDate`↔`java.sql.Date`. `Instant`↔`java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: But those are Java 8 methods, right? We're stuck using Java 7.

Comment: @ktm5124 Look for bullets at the end of my Answer, re: using the back-port of *java.time* to Java 6 & 7. FYI, the JSR 310 spec, the *java.time* implementation, and the *ThreeTen-Backport* project (as well as *Joda-Time*, the predecessor) are all led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen). Nearly identical API used in the back-port, so that when you eventually migrate away you’ll need do little more than search-and-replace your `import` statements. One notable exception is the conversion methods, located in the utilities class, `DateTimeUtils`.

Comment: I appreciate the informative answer, but there's a very high chance that no matter our efforts we are stuck using `java.util.Date`. For one thing, we have a chain of method calls that pass `java.util.Date` at every level. Either we would have to modify each of these method signatures or we'd have to replace a `java.util.Date` with an Instant at the very last moment, which would include making many changes all over the place since this is not just for one single service method or SQL query, but for many. Given this, what will happen if we use `java.util.Date` in the aforementioned way?

Comment: @ktm5124 If you decide to ignore my advice and the opinion of Sun, Oracle, the JCP, and the expert Stephen Colebourne, and choose to use `java.util.Date` then you will need to study the behavior of your JDBC driver. As I explained above, square-peg, round-hole — two different data types at play with entirely different meanings. A `java.util.Date` represents a moment, a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` does not. I do not know if the JDBC spec outlines behavior for this mismatch. In contrast, `java.time.LocalDateTime` *does* correlate directly to `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

Comment: Is there a way to convert from java.util.Date to Instant (or LocalDateTime) using Three Ten Backport? As I said, we're stuck with Java 7 so we would have to depend on Three Ten Backport for this.